# how to change the width of a svg line dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg

i wrote the following code which successfully increase the size of `svg` line but fails to decrease the size of it. Following is the code:

```js
 
 var x = function(a,s){
  var line = document.getElementById('l1');
  if (s > line.getAttribute(a) ) { // if s i greater
    for (var i = line.getAttribute(a); i<=s;i++ ){
    line.setAttribute(a, i);
    }
  };

  if(s < line.getAttribute(a)){
    for (var i = line.getAttribute(a); i<s;i-- ){
    line.setAttribute(a, i);
    }
  };

 };
  
  x('x2', 400); // changes the width of the svg 
  x('x2', 40); // fail
```

```html
<html>

<body>

 <svg heigth="210" width="500" id="svg1" >

  <line id="l1" x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(250,30,0); stroke-width:2"/>
 </svg> 


</body>
</html>
```

as you can see that it is able to increase its width but is not able to decrease it?

i am confused in the second if statement in `i<s` and `i--` and i think there is all the mistake(perhaps not)

it would be so kind if you could explain your answer so that it may be useful not only to me but for others too.

thanks!

Comment: try `for (var i = line.getAttribute(a); i > s;i--)` for size decrease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works

```
if(s < line.getAttribute(a)){
                for (var i = line.getAttribute(a); i > s;i-- ){ //changes here
                line.setAttribute(a, i);
                }
        };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4xnpn3wj/